# Multi-Dimensional Arrays in R

Tags: r

I was trying out something in R when I noticed this. I initialize a 3D array with zeroes, and then use an out-of-range first index for assignment operation.

```
arr = array(0, c(22, 246, 2))
arr[3463] = 0.15
```

Now I can also access this value using `arr[9, 158, 1]`.

`arr[3463] == arr[9, 158, 1]` returns `TRUE`

How is the out-of-range first index (`3463`) being mapped to the 3 indices (`9, 158, 1`)?

Comment: It's not out of range. See `?"["`, section `Matrices and arrays`. Try also `length(arr)` and `dim(arr)` to see the difference.

Comment: In addition to all comments/answers see, also, `arrayInd(3463, dim(arr))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is no more than a vector with attributes as dimensions. The total length of your array is thus `22*246*2 = 10824` and `3463` is not ouf of index in `arr`.

Now to understand why there is this mapping `arr[3463] == arr[9, 158, 1]`, it's simple arithmetic: `3463 = 157*22+9`.

Values taken in the array with an index (such that `3463`) are taken with the most left dimension. So you start with the first matrix of `22*246` elements, on the first column and you read row per row. You read thus all data (`22`). Then you go to the second column and read all rows (at this stage you read `44` data). And so on.

You finally arrive on row `9` of column `158` of the first matrix.

Answer (score 4):

An array is just a vector with a dimension attribute. Thus, you can also use vector subset assigning with it. This is easier to see with a 2-dimensional array a.k.a. a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(1:16, 4)
dput(m)
#structure(1:16, .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
m[7] <- 0
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
#[3,]    3    0   11   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

Note how the seventh value in the vector was changed.

Comment: Ah, the beauty of an easy to understand q/a ;) (+1)