# Getting an element from an array using a vector as an index

Tags: arrays, r

Given the K_matrix matrix

```
> K=4;
> K_matrix = array(runif(K*K) , dim = rep(2,K), dimnames = NULL)
> K_matrix

, , 1, 1

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3919999 0.2033387
[2,] 0.7053074 0.6531753

, , 2, 1

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.9474465 0.6097955
[2,] 0.7115899 0.8040770

, , 1, 2

           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.01687723 0.6536963
[2,] 0.91289535 0.5464496

, , 2, 2

          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.3858341 0.7031602
[2,] 0.7991189 0.1577894
```

If I execute,

```
> K_matrix[2,1,1,1]
[1] 0.7053074
```

I get the "second" element. However, if I try to get the same result by using a vector (vec) that contains the coordinates of the second element, I get something like this:

```
> vec = c(2,1,1,1)
> K_matrix[vec]
[1] 0.7053074 0.3919999 0.3919999 0.3919999
```

,which is not the expected result. How can I can solve this issue?

Comment: `vec = cbind(2,1,1,1) ; K_matrix[vec]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-Dimensional Arrays in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145718/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-r)

Comment: `K_matrix[c(2,1,1,1)]` returns the 2nd, 1st, 1st, 1st values of your array. Each of the 16 numbers can be referenced by index `1:16`

Comment: @akrun I think Vlo should do so as he actually provided the reason.

Comment: Also `K_matrix[t(vec)]` if you already created a vector

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Using the K_matrix[t(vec)] mentioned by @akrun is exactly was I was trying to achieve.